# oracle sql return unmatched results only between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, comparison

i need to return the unmatched results between two tables where only partial data overlaps between the two tables with no primary key on either table. the oracle sql database is version 11ish. The desired output is to roll up the sales names into a comma separated string. I'm coming from teradata sql knowledge (beginner) and converting to oracle sql on an older database and running into syntax and supported function challenges.

```
Tables
```

[image: Table1]

[image: Table2]

[image: Desired Output]

I've tried using a full outer join, which doesnt work without the primary key, i've tried not in, !=, != ANY (string) and neither are producing the output. Even if the output is 1 record for each unmatched result similar to table 1, than I can use listagg function to put in a comma-separated string.

I've tried searching and not sure the best approach, anyone have suggestions or recommendations? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Please explain the logic for the result set *in the question*.  It is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listagg()`:

```
select prop_id, sales_cde,
       listagg(sales_name, ',') within group (order by lvl)
from t
group by pop_id, sales_cde;
```

EDIT:

Oh, you seem to want codes that don't appear twice.  You can get the codes using:

```
select prop_id,
       max(max(sales_cd)) over (partition by pro_id) as sales_cd,
       sales_name, count(*) as cnt
from ((select prop_id, sales_name, sales_cde
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select prop_id, sales_name, null
       from table2
      ) 
     ) t12
group by prop_id, sales_name;
```

Then you want to `listagg()` the ones that appear only once:

```
select prop_id, sales_cd,
       listagg(case when cnt = 1 then sales_name end, ',') within group (order by sales_name)
from (select prop_id,
             max(max(sales_cd)) over (partition by pro_id) as sales_cd,
             sales_name, count(*) as cnt
      from ((select prop_id, sales_name, sales_cde
             from table1
            ) union all
            (select prop_id, sales_name, null
             from table2
            ) 
           ) t12
      group by prop_id, sales_name
     ) t12
group by prop_id, sales_cde;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding but not quite complete. the list agg function helps to aggregate yes, but before i can aggregate the final results, I need additional code to provide the unmatched results first. For example, prop id '021' for sale code 'def123' has sale names as 'ab' , 'ef', and  'to' for a total count of 3 out of the 5 options, however it's missing values 'cd' and 'mr' - I need these two missing values to be in the result set (then preference is to put in aggregated string). The unmatched results is the piece I have not been able to solve for. Thoughts?

Comment: @M.Reeves . . . I think I understand.  Check the edit.